# ImageViews Arent Visible in Android Relative Layout - XML Formatting Issue

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I've created a RelativeLayout containing several ImageViews (which after debugging are not null) however something in my XML layout is causing them not to appear.

Can anyone spot what it might be? This is driving me nuts.

### XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/downloadLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_ListView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight="0.3" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/background"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/boxart"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_gravity="left" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_ListView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_weight="0.7" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_ListView2a"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
        </RelativeLayout>

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressbar_Horizontal"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="340dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:max="100"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbar2" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/downloadbtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/progressbar_Horizontal"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/button_download" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VeNJ.png

Comment: Do you set the drawable images for your other `ImageView`s programmatically? It looks like you only define an image resource for 1 of your 3 `ImageView`s.

Comment: **1** weights only work in LinearLayouts. **2** Avoid nesting layouts, if you are not in deadly danger.

Comment: Well you haven't spedified android:src="@drawable/button_download" attribute for your first and second ImageView there is no content to wrap  and also show a screenShot what you trying to achieve (can be easily made in paint or photoshop)

Comment: Can you post your drawables u used in this xml

Comment: @Chamatke - Yes - I am using picasso (the issue lies within my XML - I am sure - if I switch to an older version of it I can see the boxart image on the left hand side)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're setting the source for the first two ImageViews programatically from your code, because if you're not, those two are empty. They should be visible if you put an image on them

The second RelativeLayout has 0dp width which makes the whole view and all its children invisible.

In an unrelated note, layout_weight doesn't work for RelativeLayouts, that attribute works only in LinearLayouts.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to give some background color each layout and view to debug your XML. Also put image view source as ic_launcher drawable to know what is wrong. Ex:for imageview
android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"

Hope this helps